# Call to OData service from C#

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, odata

I use the code below to call an OData service *(which is the working service from Odata.org)*  from C# and I don't get any result.
The error is in the `response.GetResponseStream()`.

Here is the error :

```
Length = 'stream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

I want to call to the service and parse the  data from it, what is the simpliest way to do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    public class Class1
        {

        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            Class1.CreateObject();
            }
        private const string URL = "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=atom";


        private static void CreateObject()
            {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "GET";

            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {

                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran your code on my machine, and it executed fine, I was able to traverse all XML elements retrieved by the XmlTextReader.

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "GET";

    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Accept = "application/xml";
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

But as @qujck suggested, take a look at HttpClient. It's much easier to use.

Comment: Can you please add the code which help you to see the response data

Answer (score 5):

If you're running .NET 4.5 then take a look at `HttpClient` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx))

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
Stream stream = await response
    .Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

See [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=789) for complete examples

Comment: When I try to use your code in console application I got error for the HTTP :'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly .I am using .net 4.55,what should I do to avoid this errors?

Comment: have you installed the Web API Client Libraries? Follow this guide: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Typo: _client instead of client to match declared name.